# Player moving in camera direction and being able to jump without an animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a code that allows my player to follow the camera direction, I am unable to implement jumping that is quick and not animation based.

I have looked at many youtube videos but none provide a jumping mechanic with a third person camera. The only one that had something similar was with a first person camera but the jumping was animation based, with the kind of level mechanics im making it is uncompatible.

This is my Player movement code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OldPlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string mouseXInputName;
    [SerializeField] private float mouseSensitivity;
    CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 5;

    float verticalVelocity;
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis(mouseXInputName) * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVelocity = -1 * Time.deltaTime;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
            {
                verticalVelocity = 20 * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            verticalVelocity -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        Vector3 moveDelta = new Vector3(x, verticalVelocity, z);
        controller.Move(moveDelta);
    }
}


This is my Camera Code


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string mouseXInputName, mouseYInputName;
    [SerializeField] private float mouseSensitivity;

    //[SerializeField] private Transform playerBody;

    private float xAxisClamp;
    private void Awake()
    {
        LockCursor();
        xAxisClamp = 0.0f;
    }
    private void LockCursor()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        CameraRotation();
    }
    private void CameraRotation()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis(mouseXInputName) * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis(mouseYInputName) * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xAxisClamp += mouseY;

        if(xAxisClamp > 60.0f)
        {
            xAxisClamp = 60.0f;
            mouseY = 0.0f;
            ClampXAxisRotationToValue(300.0f);
        }
        else if (xAxisClamp < -60.0f)
        {
            xAxisClamp = -60.0f;
            mouseY = 0.0f;
            ClampXAxisRotationToValue(60.0f);
        }


        transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);
       // playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }

    private void ClampXAxisRotationToValue(float value)
    {
        Vector3 eulerRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
        eulerRotation.x = value;
        transform.eulerAngles = eulerRotation;
    }
}
```

Currently I am able to move the character in the direction of the camera, but no matter what I cant't seem to implement a jumping mechanic, I moved the rotation of the player's body to the x axis because I was having issues with the body deforming when using a platform that effected the player's transform. The game I am making is a platformer so jumping is essential but not being able to turn in a new direction makes the game too linear.

Comment: Might want to add some tags as this is for.. Unity I think?